# Trying to capture the return data from an SSO request using Javascript

Tags: javascript, single-sign-on, saml

This is something pretty new to me so I'm not really sure where to even start looking.

I am building a site for a business that has been providing it's own REST API's for all the functionality they want.  This included the initial log in.

They are now moving to a SAML model (provided by Ping Federated) and I am very lost trying to figure out what I need to do on my end.  They have provided me with a URL to redirect to.  When I go to this URL there is a form to fill out username and password.  Once submitted, it jumps to another system generates a string that I need to capture at some kind of endpoint URL.  I have the endpoint URL and when I manually step through the process I do see all the steps and get a successful return string.

I can not seem to figure out how to capture that string response properly.  Any help pointing me to appropriate sources of information would be greatly appreciated.  You may safely assume that I have only the most basic understanding of SAML at this point.  I also have no access to the back end of this process, only my javascript/jQuery code.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know where this string is stored ? Did you have a look at a network trace created by your favorite browsers developer tools ?

Comment: Usually with Ping Identity, they send information back in the Headers starting with `PF_`

Comment: Marged - The string is just the content returned.  It gets directly displayed as if it were a web page but of course there is no actual HTML here, just the string.  The trace that I get from the developer tools network shows the final step at being a page called "idmanager-endpoint" as a "document" type.  It is the content of the document that I need to be able to capture.

Comment: Sorry, had more to add.  To the best of my knowledge I should be able to, when a user comes to my start page, redirect them to the webpage set up by Ping to collect the username and password, and wait for this ultimate response, but while I'm used to issuing XMLHttpRequests to be able to handle the REST Api my client offered, this doesn't seem to be the correct way to handle working with this SAML/SSO stuff and I am not sure what I should be doing to capture that final "document".  Thanks!